# Returning object before modifying it in __next__()

Tags: python, function, iterator, return

I'm programming an iterator object that returns modifications of itself and I want the original object to be part of the iteration process, so it needs to be returned before being modified.

...but:

- Creating a deepcopy of the object to return is very time-consuming.
- The object have lots of attributes, so defining auxiliary variables doesn't seem an elegant solution.
- `yield` inside `__next__` will not work because it returns a different type (generator) in each iteration instead.
- I could use `yield` inside `__iter__` to get an iterator but then I couldn't use `__next__` to get on-demand iterations (my object is a Turing machine, so a controlled step-by-step print of the tape would be nice).

An example of working, but inefficient, code:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class MyObject():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.n)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n >= 10:
            raise StopIteration

        self_copy = deepcopy(self)
        self.n += 1
        return self_copy

for x in MyObject(n=7):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
7
8
9
```

I'm probably missing something here but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generator seems like a good idea. Replace your `__iter__` and `__next__` with this:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        while not self.n >= 10:
            yield self
            self.n += 1
```

(In this particular case we could of course do `while self.n < 10:` instead.)

Alternatively, to make your object itself its own iterator, as discussed in our comments below, you could use a flag:

```
class MyObject():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.iterated_original = False
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.n)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.iterated_original:
            self.iterated_original = True
        else:
            self.n += 1
        if self.n >= 10:
            raise StopIteration
        return self

for x in MyObject(n=7):
    print(x)
```

Or since `iterated_original` ideally is set to `True` *after* the original has been iterated, here's as late as I can do it:

```
    def __next__(self):
        if self.iterated_original:
            self.n += 1
        if self.n >= 10:
            raise StopIteration
        try:
            return self
        finally:
           self.iterated_original = True
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but I also wanted to keep control over the iteration process, by calling next() manually and interactively. In case I don't find any elegant alternative, I'll keep your suggestion since it's the best so far.

Comment: @WHoZ What do you mean? You can do that with this.

Comment: @WHoZ Ah, I think see what you mean. You could do `myiter = iter(MyObject(n=7))` for that. Or `myobj = MyObject(n=7)` and `myiter = iter(myobj)` if you want both the "object" and the iterator. What you're describing is rather unusual, I'd say it's better to do it the normal way (treating non-iterator iterables and their iterators separately).

Comment: @WHoZ Then again, such modifications in an iterator are unusual already anyway...

Comment: By interactively I mean "obj = MyObject(n=7); next(obj); print(obj)" instead of using for loops. Unfortunately, I can't call next() on an iterator (as you made).

Comment: @WHoZ You *can* call `next()` on an iterator. But in my first solution, `obj` isn't an iterator. Just an iterable. Added a second solution now, which should achieve what you desire.